# Code not training fast. I gave 3500000 rows of input as 'data.csv' and system hanged. Even after 24 hours no output

Tags: neural-network, nltk

Trying to return the category of input data. Training data is 'data.csv' which is 3500000 rows of sentence and its class.

```
import nltk 
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer 
import os
import csv 
import json
import datetime 
stemmer = LancasterStemmer() 
training_data = []  
with open('data.csv') as f:
    training_data = [{k: str(v) for k, v in row.items()}
      for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
words = []   
classes = []  
documents = [] 
ignore_words = ['?','.','_','-']  #words to be ignored in input data file

for pattern in training_data:
    w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern['sentence'])

    words.extend(w)
  documents.append((w, pattern['class']))
    if pattern['class'] not in classes:
        classes.append(pattern['class'])


words = [stemmer.stem(a.lower()) for a in words if a not in ignore_words]
words = list(set(words)) #remove duplicates

classes = list(set(classes))
```

create our training data

```
training = []
output = []

output_empty = [0] * len(classes)


for doc in documents:
    # initialize our bag of words
    bag = []
    # list of tokenized words for the pattern
    pattern_words = doc[0]
    # stem each word
    pattern_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in pattern_words]

    for w in words:
        bag.append(1) if w in pattern_words else bag.append(0)

    training.append(bag)

    output_row = list(output_empty)
    output_row[classes.index(doc[1])] = 1
    output.append(output_row)

import numpy as np  
import time 


def sigmoid(x):
    output = 1/(1+np.exp(-x))
    return output

def sigmoid_output_to_derivative(output):
    return output*(1-output)

def clean_up_sentence(sentence):

    sentence_words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    sentence_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in sentence_words]
    return sentence_words


def bow(sentence, words, show_details=False):
    # tokenize the pattern
    sentence_words = clean_up_sentence(sentence)
    # bag of words
    bag = [0]*len(words)  
    for s in sentence_words:
        for i,w in enumerate(words):
            if w == s: 
                bag[i] = 1

    return(np.array(bag))
```

returns the calculated value of the output after multiplying with the sigmoids

```
def think(sentence, show_details=False):
    x = bow(sentence.lower(), words, show_details)
    # input layer is our bag of words
    l0 = x
    # matrix multiplication of input and hidden layer
    l1 = sigmoid(np.dot(l0, synapse_0))
    # output layer
    l2 = sigmoid(np.dot(l1, synapse_1))
    return l2
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Who knows what the problem is? You don't even give the code that trains your classifier (which classifier?). Classifiers can take a very long time to train, and with 3.5M rows, it could be working properly. Or your box could be short of memory and spending its time swapping. Or you could be using list lookups instead of set lookups somewhere. Check your system, profile your code, and when you figure out what the problem is, ask a specific question if you can't see how to solve it.

Comment: The code execution is hung at line 17, w=nltk.words_tokenize(pattern['sentence'])  for 24 hours. Is there an alternate way to do this, keeping in mind the RAM available is 4gb